# Bash case $var in multiple hits

Tags: bash, case, multiple-results

```
shopt -s extglob 
CONDITION1="@(*cheese*|*milk*|*cream*)"
CONDITION2="@(*potato*|*rice*|*pasta*)"

myvar1="pasta with cheese"

case ${myvar1} in
${CONDITION1} )
        echo DAIRY
        ;;
${CONDITION2} )
        echo CARBS
        ;;
* )
        echo HUNGRY
        ;;
esac
```

result of this script is echo DAIRY

I need to change above code so it echoes:
DIARY
CARBS

Is that possible?

Comment: `${foo}` adds nothing over `$foo` in your use cases here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `;;&` instead of `;;` if you want this behaviour.

That said, fall-through behavior will mean that you get `HUNGRY` unconditionally. I'd suggest setting a flag on matches and checking for it before emitting `HUNGRY`.

So:

```
myvar1="pasta with cheese"; matched=0
case $myvar1 in
  *cheese*|*milk*|*cream*)
     echo DAIRY; matched=1 ;;&
  *potato*|*rick*|*pasta*)
     echo CARBS; matched=1 ;;&
esac
(( matched )) || echo HUNGRY
```

That said, it would be easy enough to make this code compliant with POSIX sh by splitting into multiple case statements (and, again, not using extglobs):

```
myvar1="pasta with cheese"; unset matched
case $myvar1 in *cheese*|*milk*|*cream*) echo DAIRY; matched=1 ;; esac
case $myvar1 in *potato*|*rick*|*pasta*) echo CARBS; matched=1 ;; esac
[ "$matched" ] || echo HUNGRY
```

Comment: But note that `;;&` does not exist in bash before version 4.

Comment: ;;& is cool! :)
To avoid being HUNGRY, can't I just put it everywhere but not infront of *)? I tested it and it works.
Anyway, you offered alternative code solution, I will have to think if I can use it with many different CONDITION variables.